# AWS Redshift JDBC connection fail to execute queries

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift, jdbctemplate

I use Aws Redshift with `RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.2.0002.jar` driver.
The problem is next: 
Suppose I have two tables `A1` and `A2` .
At first I execute next query using JdbcTemplate (spring):

```
DROP TABLE A1;
```

After this:

```
ALTER TABLE A2 RENAME TO A1
```

And at second step sometimes I'm getting error like this:

*'Can't alter table as table with this name already exists'*

I already tried to use transaction block and only thing which helps me - wait few seconds after first query execution.

**Solution**:

Problem was in JdbcTemplate from Spring, seems like some incompatibility with aws redshift or bad configuration..
When I configured connection to rs using Connection calss all was ok.

Comment: Hi, Which library you are using currently instead of jdbcTemplate?

Comment: what is current status?does redshift support jdbc

Comment: Hey there - we seem to have stumbled to this ourselves. The jdbcTemplate fails to do ALTER/DROP/RENAME type queries, the Statement does not. I am not sure this is a timing issue. RedShift JDBC Driver version 1.2.8.1005. Btw, solution proposed in description is (still) a valid workaround.